# Replicate Protovis N-body simulation in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, protovis

I would like to replicate the N-Body example from Protovis in the new library D3. D3 is supposed to be an evolution of Protovis but I am having a lot of trouble getting any simulation to even come close.

Target: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/nbody.html

So far I have the following problems:

- D3 has no built in collision detection.
- When adding collision detection of my own in each tick, it's very jittery.
- The N-body example moves slowly and smoothly, this is not the case for me in D3. Trying to replicate the settings in the Force layout doesn't seem to match.
- The color ramp I can't replicate with any accuracy. Mine jitters badly when trying to base it on node velocity.
- I can't get the simulation to stay running in any reasonable way. The cooling facter I have tried setting manually and via a resume().

Here is my current attempt: https://gist.github.com/1917001

Comment: To get the simulation to run forever, I call `force.resume()` inside the "tick" handler.

Comment: Hi, can you perhaps update us on this|? :)